# ¿Qué hacer con la etiqueta "visual-basic"?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Cuando alguien habla de *Visual Basic*, normalmente se refiere a uno de los siguientes tres lenguajes de programación:

- [`vb.net`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/vb.net/info)
- [`visual-basic-6`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-basic-6/info)
- [`vba`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info)

Aunque todas comparten una similitud en su sintaxis, en realidad no son lo mismo. Y para poder contestar una pregunta correctamente, es importante tener claro cual de los 3 lenguajes es al que se refiere.

De modo que es un poco problemático cuando las preguntas usan la etiqueta [`visual-basic`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-basic/info), porque no deja claro a cual de los 3 lenguajes de programación se está refiriendo.

Antes de hacer esta pregunta en meta, esa etiqueta se encontraba en 6 preguntas solamente. 4 de entre ellas en realidad tienen que ver con `vb.net`, y 2 tienen que ver con `vba`. Tal vez no he debido, pero cambié las 2 últimas para que solo quedaran con la etiqueta `vba`. Pero después de hacer esos 2 cambios, me frené, y lo vi mejor de hacer esta pregunta.

Mi duda es, ¿qué se debería hacer con esta etiqueta? Porque, por sí sola, no es muy útil. Mas bien, es ambígua.

¿Deberíamos modificar las etiquetas de las 4 preguntas que le quedan para que usen `vb.net` mas bien, y luego eliminar la etiqueta `visual-basic`? O, ¿se debería crear un sinónimo de `visual-basic` a `vb.net`, ya que parece ser la interpretación mas probable? ¿Alguna otra opción?

Comment: visual-basic de hecho no existe en SO en inglés, en cambio se tiene vba y visual-basic-applications

Comment: @Elenasys: Yo preferiría eliminar `visual-basic` francamente, aunque sí me gusta lo de los otros sinónimos para tener tanto la versión larga como la corta de las diferentes etiquetas.

Comment: Discusión generada en el chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33674437#33674437

Comment: Solicitado en [Quemar etiqueta [visual-basic\]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1730/127) y [Sinónimos de etiquetas de Visual Basic](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1736/127)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Editado:** Luego de la discusión en el chat y la [respuesta de Elenasys](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1084/127), parecería ser mejor opción quemar a la etiqueta [visual-basic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic) y generar los otros sinónimos.

---

> Tal vez no he debido, pero cambié las 2 últimas para que solo quedaran con la etiqueta [vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)

Es exactamente lo mejor que podías hacer.

> ¿qué se debería hacer con esta etiqueta?

<s>En mi opinión, debería ser un sinónimo de [vb.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), ya que es lo que creo que se debería entender cuando uno dice "Visual Basic".</s>

Además, coincide con el mayor uso que se le ha dado. Y creo que las 2 que se usó para VBA es porque el usuario intentó escribir "visual basic para aplicaciones" (o similar) y es la única etiqueta que encontró.

Luego de ver las opiniones en el chat, estoy optando por quemar la etiqueta.

> ¿Alguna otra opción?

Para evitar futuros problemas, generaría 4 nuevas etiquetas, [visual-basic.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic.net), [visual-basic-aplicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-aplicaciones), [visual-basic-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-script) y [vb6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6) como sinónimos. De esta forma, al escribir "visual basic" (o similares) en el campo de etiquetas, le presentaría al usuario todas las opciones.

Se quemaría:

1. [visual-basic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic)  = [solicitud-de-quemado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-quemado)[burninate-request](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request)

Quedarían los siguientes sinónimos:

1. [vb.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) ← [visual-basic.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic.net)
2. [vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) ← [visual-basic-aplicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-aplicaciones) <sup>* Esta última tiene el máximo de 25 caracteres.</sup>
3. [vbscript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) ← [visual-basic-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-script)
4. [vb6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6) ←
   [visual-basic-6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-6)

Comment: El único problema es que no tengo suficientes puntos para proponer sinónimos en esas etiquetas. :(

Comment: @sstan Listo... Como vengo comentando, no me es tan importante el cómo, sino hacer algo por mejorar el uso del sitio

Comment: [tag:visual-basic] aún no ha sido quemada. Investigando si hay una publicación específica sobre esto.

Comment: Solicitud de quemado publicada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1730/65

Comment: Gracias @Rubén. En su momento había tenido pocos votos, y dejamos este tema "durmiendo"... Tanto que ya me había olvidado. Genial que lo reactives.

Comment: No hay qué. Por cierto, ¿alguna vez hubo preguntas con [tag:vb6]?

Comment: @Rubén Creo que sí, pero no me acuerdo. La idea de estos sinónimos es generar la misma lógica en la nomenclatura, siendo coherentes con VB. Que cuando alguien escriba "VB" le aparezcan todas. Además, siempre lo llamé "vb6", al igual que profesionales que usaban este lenguaje.

Comment: @Mariano: Eso lo entiendo, pero para que exista una etiqueta alguien tiene que crearla ¿te animas? :)

Comment: @Rubén Sí. Claro. Me encargo de seguir esa parte

Comment: Creada la sugerencia de hacer [tag:visual-basic-aplicaciones] sinónimo de [tag:vba], véase https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1898/65

Answer (score 5):

Vamos por partes, para empezar:

## Visual Basic 6 != Visual Basic .Net != VBA != VBScript

> ¿Deberíamos modificar las etiquetas de las 4 preguntas que le quedan
> para que usen vb.net mas bien, y luego eliminar la etiqueta
> visual-basic? O, ¿se debería crear un sinónimo de visual-basic a
> vb.net, ya que parece ser la interpretación mas probable? ¿Alguna otra
> opción?

Si alguien pregunta por Visual Basic va a ejecutarse como una 'macro' dentro de algun programa de Microsoft Office, se refiere a VBA, y no es sinónimo de Visual Basic, tampoco de VB.net ni de VB6.0 porque VBA tiene un conjunto limitado de características en comparación a este par de lenguajes.

Si alguien pregunta por Visual Basic, así tal cual, se refiere a **VB 6**, conocido también como **VB 6.0**

Si alguien pregunta por **Visual Basic .Net**, se refiere a **VB.net**, versión que se lanzó con **Visual Studio .net 2003**

Hay una 4ta etiqueta: **VBScript**, que se puede ejecutar bajo windows tranquilamente.

En lo personal siento que cada etiqueta debe trabajarse por separado, adicionalmente al revisar las preguntas, asignarle adecuadamente en base a la información de la pregunta.

En SOen tenemos lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente definicion fredyfx

Comment: gracias hermano :D vamos aportando para crecer entre todos :D

Comment: *Si alguien pregunta por Visual Basic, así tal cual, se refiere a VB 6*: esa es la única parte que no estoy de acuerdo. No todo el que dice `Visual Basic` se refiere a `VB6`. Fue cierto cuando a penas empezaba VB.NET. Pero mas y mas, `Visual Basic` se refiere a VB.NET en la mente de las personas. De allí el problema con esa etiqueta: por sí sola es ambigua.

Comment: acabas de mencionar algo importante: "cuando a penas empezaba VB.net", creo que programadores que llevan tiempo conocen la diferencia, por lo que siento, vamos a tener que tener buen ojo con las preguntas y editarlas de ahora en adelante con todo el power 2.0!

Answer (score 4):

En el caso de SO en inglés la etiqueta <kbd>visual-basic</kbd> no existe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**opino que debería ser quemada**, en su caso existiría:

<kbd>vba</kbd> y posiblemente <kbd>aplicaciones-visual-basic</kbd>

Comment: En [so] no existe la etiqueta `visual-basic` pero sí `vb` la cual está marcada como sinónimo de la etiqueta `vb.net`.

Answer (score -2):

Supongo que ya se solucionó el problema, ya que no veo que esas etiquetas tengan preguntas, pero doy mi respuesta en cómo lo veo ahora.

Actualmente veo estas:

- [visual-basic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic), [visual-basic-6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-6), [vb.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), [vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), [vbscript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript).

Creo que no hay que hacer nada... Todas son cosas diferentes.

Si las preguntas están mal etiquetadas, hay que volver a etiquetarlas a mano, a no ser que exista algo como **renombramiento de etiquetas**, pero en ese caso, sería necesario solo si todas las preguntas de esa etiqueta están mal.

Comment: Un sinónimo es exactamente eso: renombra una etiqueta a otra

Comment: @Mariano Yo digo de un renombramiento pero sin que la original aparezca en la lista.

Comment: Cuando se genera un sinónimo, la etiqueta hija deja de aparecer en la lista

Comment: @Mariano Ah, era eso.

Comment: @Mariano Pero a lo que me refiero es... Aún así, queda registrado que es un sinónimo, y ese no era mi punto.