# Quemar etiqueta [visual-basic]

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

En [¿Qué hacer con la etiqueta "visual-basic"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1045/65) se discutió acerca de [visual-basic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic). La respuesta aceptada con un balance de siete votos positivos a la fecha recomienda el quemado de la etiqueta en cuestión.

A nombre de la comunidad, se solicita a los moderadores diamantados que procedan a ello.

Comment: Es justo y necesario, para mantener la organización y el orden del sitio :D

Comment: Gracias por hacer la petición. En preparación de que un moderador elimine la etiqueta, repasé todas las preguntas que la usaban y *corregí* las etiquetas lo mejor que pude, de modo que no queden más preguntas que usen la etiqueta `visual-basic`.

Comment: Solicitud coordinada junto a [Sinónimos de etiquetas de Visual Basic](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1736/127)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta etiqueta no existe dado a que se ha removido ya de todas las preguntas asociadas y el sistema la borro.  Por eso puedo marcar esta solicitud cómo completada.