# Sinónimos de etiquetas de Visual Basic

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Siguiendo la propuesta de [¿Qué hacer con la etiqueta "visual-basic"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1045/127), con la respuesta aceptada con `+10 | -1` actualmente, les pido si podrán generar los siguientes:

**Sinónimos**

1. [vb.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) ← [visual-basic.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic.net)
2. [vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) ← [visual-basic-aplicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-aplicaciones) <sup>* Esta última tiene el máximo de 25 caracteres.</sup>
3. [vbscript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) ← [visual-basic-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-script)
4. [vb6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6) ←
   [visual-basic-6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-6)

> Recién generé las etiquetas que faltaban para poder generar los sinónimos.

Comment: Solicitud coordinada junto a [Quemar etiqueta [visual-basic\]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1730/127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He creado 3 de los 4 sinónimos de etiqueta, y la otra ya había sido aprobada.

La lista de sinónimos de etiqueta queda de la siguiente manera:

> Las de la izquierda son etiquetas maestras, mientras que las de la derecha son el sinónimo.
>
> 1. [vb.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) ← [visual-basic.net](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic.net) (acabo de hacer el sinónimo)
> 2. [vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) ← [visual-basic-aplicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-aplicaciones) (esta ya había sido aprobada la sugerencia de @Rubén)
> 3. [vbscript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) ← [visual-basic-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-script) (acabo de hacer el sinónimo)
> 4. [vb6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6) ← [visual-basic-6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-6) (acabo de hacer el sinónimo)

Comment: **[genio genio genio!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Emtw0TH_9I)**

Answer (score 1):

## [visual-basic-aplicaciones] sinónimo de [vba]

En esta pregunta y en la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1047/65) a [¿Qué hacer con la etiqueta "visual-basic"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1045/65) Mariano sugiere, entre otras, que hagamos [visual-basic-aplicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-aplicaciones) sinónimo de [vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). Recién sugerí sinónimo. Les dejo el enlace para votar

https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/synonyms