# Hagamos [visual-basic-aplicaciones] sinónimo de [vba]

Tags: discusión, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

En la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1047/65) a [¿Qué hacer con la etiqueta "visual-basic"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1045/65) Mariano sugiere, entre otras, que hagamos [visual-basic-aplicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-aplicaciones) sinónimo de [vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). Recién sugerí sinónimo. Les dejo el enlace para votar

https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/synonyms